# Category of all classes

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

What is the easiest way to see that the category of all classes runs into logical problems. By easiest I mean avoids as much formal logic as possible.

Comment: In what sense is that a problem? Other than "proper classes are not elements of other classes", so if $\bf C$ was the category of classes, $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathbf C)$ would be a class containing classes, and therefore a class of sets. But if you have a meta-theory, then you can certainly talk about the category of all classes. Likewise, if you have a foundation where $2$-classes are a thing, that's also possible.

Comment: There are "only" "logical" problems here, not "real" ones.

Comment: Personally, I think it runs into the same kind of problems that Russell discovered with set theory and is generally artifically managed rather than solved. For me, the real insight was given by Aristotle who said the infinite was characterised by its inexhaustability hence any solution to this is a kind of artifical cutoff. For example, with the usual set theory we end with classes and no 2-class of classes.

Comment: The nifty result I saw once, and had related in my now deleted answer, which wasn't well received, is that it would contain its power set, and thus have cardinality bigger than itself.